# How To redirect To A specific Part of page in PHP like in Html We it By Id="abc" and then we do <a>href="#abc"</a>

Tags: php, html

```
<p class="leading-relaxed">This course is based on Ethical Hacking from beginning, whoever is a beginner in this field or don't know from where to start can start from this course.....</p>


<a href="/ehacking.html#security"class="text-indigo-500 inline-flex items-center mt-4" target="_blank">Learn More
```

its in html but how do I rediect any specific part of page in php like in html i do `<a> href="/ehacking.html#security"</a>`

Comment: Remember that PHP runs before the page is sent to the browser. The browser will receive just the HTML, so anchor links are created within the HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create URL to target page with anchor at the end and redirect to it in PHP.

For example `/ehacking.html#security`. There's no difference what adds anchor to location, browser or your backend.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#anchor